# Addtocart Rest api for Configurable product in magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, rest-api

Addtocart Rest api for Configurable product in magento2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add a configurable product to a cart

To add a configurable product to a cart, you must specify the `sku` as well as the set of `option_id/option_value` pairs that make the `product configurable`.

In this example, we’ll add the Chaz Kangeroo Hoodie (sku: MH01) configurable product to the cart. This product comes in three colors (black, gray, and orange) and five sizes (XS, S, M, L, XL). In the sample data, the option_id values for Size and Color are 141 and 93, respectively. You can use the GET /V1/configurable-products/:sku/options/all call to determine the option_id values for the given SKU.

The `GET /V1/configurable-products/:sku/children` call returns information about each combination of color and size, 15 in all for MH01. The following sample shows the returned values for size and color for a small gray Chaz Kangeroo Hoodie.

```
{
  "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "size",
      "value": "168"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "color",
      "value": "52"
    }
  ]
}
```

We now know the values for option_value for size and color are 168 and 52, so we’re ready to add the product to the cart.

> Endpoint

POST /rest//V1/carts/mine/items

> Headers

Content-Type application/json

Authorization Bearer

> Payload

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "MH01",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "4",
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": 52
          },
          {
            "option_id": "141",
            "option_value": 168
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

> Response

```
{
    "item_id": 13,
    "sku": "MH01-S-Gray",
    "qty": 1,
    "name": "Chaz Kangeroo Hoodie",
    "price": 52,
    "product_type": "configurable",
    "quote_id": "4",
    "product_option": {
        "extension_attributes": {
            "configurable_item_options": [
                {
                    "option_id": "93",
                    "option_value": 52
                },
                {
                    "option_id": "141",
                    "option_value": 168
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items.html

**I hope this will help**

Comment: not working $productData = [
     "cartItem"=> [
    "sku" => "WH11",
    "qty" => 1,
    "quote_id" => $quote_id,
    "product_option" => [
      "extension_attributes"=> [
        "configurable_item_options"=> [
  [
            "option_id"=> "93",
            "option_value"=> 50
   
            
  ],[
    "option_id" => "141",
            "option_value" => 166
    
  ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    
  ]
 ];

Comment: $ch = curl_init("http://example.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/items");
curl_setopt($ch, CURL OPT_CUSTOM REQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($productData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

Comment: My bad i missed out the option value . Its working fine now